# Gradle - Default configuration for PMD/FindBugs

Tags: gradle, findbugs, pmd

I have PMD and FindBugs configured in eclipse as well as Gradle. The Gradle reports are consumed by Jenkins, which lists a set of violations, which seem to be different than those reported by Eclipse.

I would like to set my Eclipse FindBugs and PMD settings to be the same as the defaults for the corresponding Gradle Plugins.

What are the default PMD RuleSets and FindBugs effort configured for the Gradle Plugins ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation for the `findBugs` gradle plugin [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.FindBugsExtension.html) and `PMD` plugin [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.PmdExtension.html).

For `findbugs`, it uses `effort = 'default'`. See the [documentation](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/manual/running.html#commandLineOptions) for findBugs to see what that entails.

For `PMD`, it looks like it uses `"basic"`. You can check out the `PMD` [docs](http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/rules/index.html#Basic_Rules) to see what that entails.